# Swift Unit testing with XCTAssertThrows analogue

Tags: swift

Is there any equivalent to check for throwing exceptions in swift language Unit tests?

For example I Have a class:

```
class Square : NSObject{

    let sideLength: Int

    init(sideLength: Int) {
        assert(sideLength >= 0, "Wrong initialization of Square class with below zero side length")
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init()
    }
}
```

and Test to check it work. In objective C I can write test method like this:

```
- (void)testInitializationWithWrongSideLengthThrowsExceptions{
   XCTAssertThrows([[Shape alloc] initWithSideLength: -50], "Should throw exceptions on wrong side values initialisations");
}
```

What is Swift equal technic?

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar: Please just stop retagging Swift questions altogether. You're not helping. At all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the following three files to your tests:

```
//  ThrowsToBool.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/// A 'pure' closure; has no arguments, returns nothing.
typedef void (^VoidBlock)(void);

/// Returns: true if the block throws an `NSException`, otherwise false
BOOL throwsToBool(VoidBlock block);


//  ThrowsToBool.m
#import "ThrowsToBool.h"

BOOL throwsToBool(VoidBlock const block) {
    @try {
        block();
    }
    @catch (NSException * const notUsed) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}


// xxxTests-Bridging-Header.h
#import "ThrowsToBool.h"
```

Then you can write:

```
XCTAssert(throwsToBool {
   // test code that throws an NSException
})
```

But it doesn't work for assert or precondition :(

PS I got the idea from: http://modocache.io/xctest-the-good-parts

Answer (score 2):

I think the `assert()`-function should only be used for debug-purposes. Not only because of the following statement from Apple's Swift-Book (https://itun.es/de/jEUH0.l):

*„Assertions cause your app to terminate and are not a substitute for designing your code in such a way that invalid conditions are unlikely to arise.“*

Thats why I would solve this as follows:

```
import Cocoa
import XCTest

class Square
{
    let sideLength: Int

    init(_ sideLength: Int)
    {
        self.sideLength = sideLength >= 0 ? sideLength : 0
    }
}

class SquareTests: XCTestCase
{
    override func setUp() { super.setUp() }
    override func tearDown() { super.tearDown() }

    func testMySquareSideLength() {
        let square1 = Square(1);
        XCTAssert(square1.sideLength == 1, "Sidelength should be 1")

        let square2 = Square(-1);
        XCTAssert(square2.sideLength >= 0, "Sidelength should be not negative")
    }
}

let tester = SquareTests()
tester.testMySquareSideLength()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to XCTAssertThrows in swift. For now you can't use a native function, but there is a solution with some objective-c help. You can use Quick, or only Nimble. Or to make your own assert function - see this article - http://modocache.io/xctest-the-good-parts - Potential Improvement #2: Add XCTAssertThrows to Swift

Answer (score 0):

the best way is add a bridge I think.

please look at https://gist.github.com/akolov/8894408226dab48d3021

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

correct way in Swift 2:

```
class Square : NSObject{

    let sideLength: Int

    init(sideLength: Int) throws { // throwable initializer
        guard sideLength >= 0 else { // use guard statement
           throw ...// your custom error type
        }

        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init()
    }
}
```

and testing:

```
func testInitThrows() {
        do {
            _ = try Square(sideLength: -1) // or without parameter name depending on Swift version
            XCTFail()
        } catch ... { // your custom error type

        } catch {
            XCTFail()
        }
    }
```