# How to write a unit test in iOS for an expected assert/assertionFailure?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, assertions, xctest

### UPDATE:

It looks like this functionality should be supported in the upcoming [Swift 2.0](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=29)/XCode 7 versions, which apparently will include try/catch goodness, so this question will likely be moot. I'll try to update this post accordingly when they are out of beta.

### ORIGINAL QUESTION:

In Swift, though I assume the question/answer would be applicable to Objective-C, I want to write a function `foo` of the format:

```
public class SomeClass{
  public func foo(someString:String){
    //validate someString
    assert(!someString.isEmpty, "The someString parameter cannot be empty.")
  }
}
```

I use an `assert` call because I believe this is what is recommended by Apple as opposed to throwing exceptions, as is common in other languages.

However, in my unit test, I want to be able to ensure that the function indeed fails when the `someString` parameter is an empty String:

```
class SomeClass_Tests:XCTestCase{
  func test_foo_someStringParamaterIsEmpty_error(){
    //ACTION
    let someClassInstance = SomeClass()
    someClassInstance.foo("")

    //VALIDATE
    //**What goes here?
  }
}
```

I can find no documentation or posts regarding this situation, even though I believe this is a highly important unit test to ensure proper behavior and usage of classes and libraries.

In other languages that include exceptions/exception handling, the `assert` would be replaced with something like `throw SomeError()` and then, in the unit test you could simply wrap the action in a `try`/`catch` block and assert that the exception was indeed set, like this:

```
class SomeClass_Tests:XCTestCase{
  func test_foo_someStringParamaterIsEmpty_error(){
    //ACTION
    let someClassInstance = SomeClass()

    var expectedException:SomeException? = nil
    try{
      someClassInstance.foo("")
    }catch(someException:SomeException){
      expectedException = someException
    }

    //VALIDATE
    XCTAssertIsNotNil(expectedException)
  }
}
```

But there are no such constructs or equivalent work-arounds in Swift that I've seen in the documentation. Are there any known solutions or workarounds for performing tests like this?

Comment: You’re absolutely right that XCTest ought to have a did-assert or did-not-assert assertion (though it’s slightly complicated by build configs enabling/disabling assertions - more useful to test preconditions and fatal errors probably). Brian Gesiak wrote [this post](http://modocache.io/xctest-the-good-parts) about some of the limitations and filed [this radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/20066350) about assertions specifically.

Comment: Thanks @AirspeedVelocity, those links were very useful. I think the lack of true "exceptions" was forged through a bit of hubris (reminiscent of when junior developers equate "exception throwing" with "bug throwing"), and for me, is quickly becoming a sore spot on what I think is otherwise a reasonably enjoyable language/framework.

Comment: I’m on the fence about exceptions. On the one hand, yes it would be nice to be able to catch accidental overflows. On the other hand, exceptions commonly used for non-truly-exceptional reasons are a complete curse in other languages… So in conclusion, I will never be happy...

Comment: Oh yeah, exceptions are definitely a classic case of the whole great power/great responsibility schtick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing assertion in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529625/testing-assertion-in-swift)

Answer (score 9):

Matt Gallagher's [CwlPreconditionTesting project on github](https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlPreconditionTesting) adds a `catchBadInstruction` function which gives you the ability to test for assertion/precondition failures in unit test code.

The [CwlCatchBadInstructionTests file](https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlPreconditionTesting/blob/master/Tests/CwlPreconditionTestingTests/CwlCatchBadInstructionTests.swift) shows a simple illustration of its use. (Note that it only works in the simulator for iOS.)

Comment: `CwlPreconditionTesting` library is integrated in Nimble now : https://github.com/Quick/Nimble#swift-assertions

Comment: second link is dead.
link https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlPreconditionTesting/blob/master/Tests/CwlPreconditionTestingTests/CwlCatchBadInstructionTests.swift

Answer (score 1):

> However, in my unit test, I want to be able to ensure that the function indeed fails when the someString parameter is an empty String

I understand just what you're trying to do, because I've done it myself in Ruby programs. But Swift (as I have had frequent occasion to observe) is not Ruby! The problem here is that you can guarantee that the function does *not* fail when the `someString` parameter is an empty string — in your actual app. This is because asserts *don't operate in a release build*.

The upshot is that you can use assert as a form of debugging during development, but if such a case can occur in real life, you should be handling it in good order, not crashing.

And thus testing for whether an assert "happened" is not really a valid unit testing technique, which is why you're having trouble using it in that way.

Comment: "but if such a case can occur in real life, you should be handling it in good order, not crashing." - to me that misses the point of exceptions. Exceptions, to me, are how developers indicate to other developers (or themselves) that a method or class is being misused in an _informative_ manner, rather than just crashing internally and inconsistently. I think it actually runs philosophically counter to the lines of thinking behind the `!` nilable operator. "Here is this super-easy debugging/production-crash-causing operator to make things safer...and...and that's all you get! Go away!" :P

Comment: "to me that misses the point of exceptions" I totally agree; hence my remark about doing this in Ruby. But I think _you_ totally miss the point of Swift not _having_ exceptions! (At least, not as a form of flow control. Yes, you can still crash at runtime, how can it be denied?!!!) I am not saying I _agree_ with Swift's philosophy, but I am saying this _is_ the philosophy and that is why you cannot do what you want to do here.

Comment: exceptions are a common objective-c paradigm for conveying fatal errors and it is to be expected that swift programs interoperating with objective-c libraries need a way to work with that paradigm.

Comment: @emish They do now! But they didn’t back when I wrote that answer. Swift has changed greatly since those days. You’re looking at history.

Answer (score 1):

why to try and catch the error and than checking what happened instead of testing that assertion is thrown ?

```
XCTAssertThrows()
```

and than to see the values
?

Comment: XCTAssertThrows is not directly available in Swift.

Comment: As of Swift 2 there is XCTAssertThrowsError, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190161/xctassertthrowserror-strange-behavior-with-custom-errorhandler

Comment: XCTAssertThrows is a function that asserts that something throws an exception. That is different from "catching" an `assert` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the `XCTAssertThrows` and `XCTAssertThrowsSpecific` macros available in XCTest framework.

Maybe you will need to replace your assert with `[NSException raise]` to make it work.

Comment: Those macros are not available in the Swift language, so my original assumption that answers would be applicable to Objective-C was incorrect. This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052739/swift-unit-testing-with-xctassertthrows-analogue) is very similar and offers some suggestions and information.

Comment: You can consider to switch your XCTestCase module to ObjC language if you really need to test the assertion.

Comment: Or (maybe it is not possible, I'm writing in swift 2 weeks only) you can try to add an ObjC category to XCTestCase swift module with a specific method which tests assertion only.