# XCTAssertThrowsError strange behavior with custom errorHandler

Tags: swift, error-handling, syntax-error, closures

In my unit test I have the following code that checks whether thrown error is of expected type. It is done with two identical statements one of which doesn't compile:

```
    enum Error: ErrorType {
        case SomeExpectedError
        case SomeUnexpectedError
    }

    func functionThatThrows() throws {
        throw Error.SomeExpectedError
    }

    // 1) this compiles fine
    XCTAssertThrowsError(try functionThatThrows()) { (error) in
        switch error {
        case Error.SomeExpectedError: break
            //everything is fine
        case Error.SomeUnexpectedError: fallthrough
        default:
            XCTFail("Unexpected error thrown")
        }
    }

    // 2) doesn't compiles at all
    XCTAssertThrowsError(try functionThatThrows()) { (error) in
        XCTAssertEqual(error as? Error, Error.SomeExpectedError)
    }
```

First statement compiles and works fine, but seconds one says me that there are two errors: 
`Errors thrown from here are not handled` and `Cannot convert value of type '(Error) -> Void' to expected argument type 'String'`.

What could be wrong with this code? What do error messages mean?

I am using Xcode 7.3 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a little research I found 2 problems with my code:

1) seems like my closure considered ["Impilictly returning"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID99) because it contains only one executable statement

2) compiler was confused by my statement since XCTAssertThows accepts one more parameter that accepts closure - it's `@autoclosure _ message: () -> String`

As a result compiler thought that I passed closure for message (IMHO confusing design decision - to pass [@autoclosure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID543) as message argument), when I actually passed closure for errorHandler.

Solutions are simple:

```
    // explicitly show closure returning type Void so that compiler couldn't
    // use it as message argument (which closure must return String)
    XCTAssertThrowsError(try functionThatThrows()) { (error) -> Void in
        XCTAssertEqual(error as? Error, Error.SomeExpectedError)
    }

    // explicitly show closure's argument type
    XCTAssertThrowsError(try functionThatThrows()) { (error: ErrorType) in
        XCTAssertEqual(error as? Error, Error.SomeExpectedError)
    }

    // use "message" parameter to preserve argument order
    XCTAssertThrowsError(try functionThatThrows(), "some message") { (error) in
        XCTAssertEqual(error as? Error, Error.SomeExpectedError)
    }

    // wrap executable line in "do {}". I guess it works because closure stops
    // being "implicitly returning" and now compiler treat it as () -> Void
    // which is expected type of errorHandler argument
    XCTAssertThrowsError(try functionThatThrows()) { (error) in
        do {
            XCTAssertEqual(error as? Error, Error.SomeExpectedError)
        }
    }
```